# Query params in Lagom

Tags: rest, service, playframework, routes, lagom

I need a service call which has two query parameters. One with a default hardcoded value and other the user would supply.
I tried creating :

`ServiceCall<NotUsed, String> randomCall(String abc)`

using `restCall(Method.GET, "/testing?a=something&abc", this::randomCall)`

But received IllegalArgumentException. Is there any way to do this in Lagom?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to have a hardcoded query param? If it's a _query_ param, it should be variable, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you want this kind of behavior, I'd probably put the query string _after_ the hardcoded param.

Answer (score 2):

You can have optional query parameters like so:

```
ServiceCall<NotUsed, String> randomCall(Optional<String> a, String abc)

restCall(Method.GET, "/testing?a&abc", this::randomCall)
```

This allows you to handle the case if a is not defined in your implementation, in your case using a default value.